# Switch statement not adding to variable. What is wrong?

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

What am I doing wrong? No matter what word is typed (In capital letters ofcourse), the program prints 0 points.

I think it has something to do with where the variable is declared, but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
    public void run() {
    String word = readLine("Enter your word here: ");
    char ch;
    int points = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<word.length();i++) {
        ch = word.charAt(i);
        switch(ch) {
        case 1: ch = 'A';
        points += 1;
        break;
        case 2: ch = 'B';
        points +=3;
        break;
        case 3: ch = 'C';
        points +=3;
        break;
        case 4: ch = 'D';
        points +=2;
        break;
        case 5: ch = 'E';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 6: ch = 'F';
        points +=4;
        break;
        case 7: ch = 'G';
        points +=2;
        break;
        case 8: ch = 'H';
        points +=4;
        break;
        case 9: ch = 'I';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 10: ch = 'J';
        points +=8;
        break;
        case 11: ch = 'K';
        points +=5;
        break;
        case 12: ch = 'L';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 13: ch = 'M';
        points +=3;
        break;
        case 14: ch = 'N';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 15: ch = 'O';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 16: ch = 'P';
        points +=3;
        break;
        case 17: ch = 'Q';
        points +=10;
        break;
        case 18: ch = 'R';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 19: ch = 'S';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 20: ch = 'T';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 21: ch = 'U';
        points +=1;
        break;
        case 22: ch = 'V';
        points +=4;
        break;
        case 23: ch = 'W';
        points +=4;
        break;
        case 24: ch = 'X';
        points +=8;
        break;
        case 25: ch = 'Y';
        points +=4;
        break;
        case 26: ch = 'Z';
        points +=10;
        break;
        }
    }
    println("Your word gave "+points+" points");
}

}
```

Comment: `charat()` returns a character, e.g. `p`. you're doing `if (p == 1)` type stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not number the cases. Do

```
 case 'A':
```

instead of

```
 case 1: ch = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

The case 1 and the char value are not matching it seems,,, first print the int value of char and replace the same value in the case ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Switch {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //String word = readLine("Enter your word here: ");
    String word ;

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    word = (input.nextLine());
char ch;
int points = 0;
for (int i = 0;i<word.length();i++) {
    ch = word.charAt(i);
    switch(ch)
    {
    case 'a': ;
    points += 1;
    break;
    case 'b':
    points +=3;
    break;
    case 'c': ch = 'C';
    points +=3;
    break;

    }
}
System.out.println("Your word gave "+points+" points");
}
```